# Design a GUI for a J2ME app

Tags: java, user-interface, java-me, interface

How do I create a J2ME app for cellphones with a GUI similar to the menus you see in Java games? I've tried MIDlets with Netbeans but they only show you one GUI element at a time. *(textbox, choice, login, etc)*

And which Java IDE would you typically design these GUIs in? Netbeans or Eclipse? and is IntelliJ IDEA usable for this aswell?

Do I have to write/get a library that draws GUI controls to screen via bitmap functions .. and keeps track of the keys pressed for focus?

Comment: In which phone are you trying with, Series 40 or S60?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use minime: http://code.google.com/p/minime/
It's an open source GUI library for j2me.  miniME works on canvas level (lowest level in j2me) to draw every control so your UI will look exactly the same whatever the handset it'll be running on.   Other advantage are:
- miniME uses its own event loop to manage user controlled event (botton pressed, softbar, ..), so you Application will "behave" the same whatever the handset.
- miniME support the concept of Views and stack of view, in order to make navigation between different view/screens very easy.

Here is an example:   A View is what you have on the screen at a given moment (for example the main menu screen), then to go to a sub menu, you create a new view, and by calling a simple API, you push it in the stack of Views.  The previous view (the main menu) is still existing, but inactive.   When the sub menu view complete his work (for example, user press back, or do a selection), you can just go back to the previous view by calling a pop api.

Answer (score 11):

Try to use LWUIT - nice UI toolkit for j2me:
https://lwuit.dev.java.net/
http://lwuit.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague to give a specific aswer, but you might want to check out [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/) or [Polish](http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/), you can develop both with either Eclipse or Netbeans.

As far as designing GUIs go, neither IDE will help from a visual perspective. J2ME UI development is all done in code, beyond creating any initial graphics in a proper graphics editor you don't get to see your output until you test.

Read up on the [LCDUI package documentation](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/package-summary.html) which explains how the UI classes work and the differences between the 'High-level' and 'low-level' APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on which IDE to use - but I do know that to create custom UI (like the ones you see in J2ME games), you have to explicitly draw the GUI controls.

Beware that you may need to customize the GUI depending on the target phones. You have to cater for different screen sizes, key pad configurations, default theme etc. This would probably mean that you need different builds for things like different screen sizes which would drive up your Java Verified certification costs (if you need it).

You may be able to find a set of nice looking UI controls that you can buy online and use (try J2ME Polish). The easy way out of course, is to use default J2ME controls :)

Answer (score 2):

Links to many j2me GUI libraries: [link1](http://newsofthefuture.net/index.php?/archives/33-Evaluation-GUI-libraries-for-J2ME.html), [link2](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Java_ME_UI_Frameworks)

I know that [kuix](http://www.kalmeo.org/projects/kuix) is not bad and free - watch demo. 
But i prefer to make my own gui elements - this is much more flexible (but takes some time).

As for IDE - you may want to make some kind of gui-editor tool, construct interface in it, save result to some file, and read it from your app.

Answer (score 1):

It's way too cumbersome to write your own GUI, especially since there are so many available these days. If you're familiar with desktop development in VB.Net and C#, you might find "J2ME GUI" easy to use. You can download it from http://www.garcer.com/. It has a similar feel and makes it easy to learn.  This is the kind of GUI that I expected to come standard with MIDP2 when I started mobile development.  Would have solved a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with web stuffs then you can use KUIX (kalmeo.org/home/index) framework having xml and css supports. In place of It you can use also Polish framework (www.j2mepolish.org) it's also uses the xml in easy way rather than kalmeo kuix framework.